# Dirac delta and trig functions

Tags: dirac-delta

I ran across the identity:
$$
\delta(f(x)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(x - x_i)}{|f^\prime(x_i)|}
$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta and $x_i$ are the roots of some function $f(x)$. Now, I have
seen in physics textbooks people use
$$
\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0) = \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\delta(r-r_0)\delta(\theta - \theta_0)\delta(\phi - \phi_0)
$$
as the Dirac delta in spherical coordinates. Where I am deeply
confused is that some replace the $\theta$ part with $\delta(\theta - \theta_0)/\sin\theta \rightarrow \delta(\cos\theta - \cos\theta_0)$.
I thought I was comfortable with this transformation because of the
above rule, but I not so sure anymore. Take for example, a line defined as $\delta(\cos^2\theta - 1)$. By the above identity, I should be able to
transform this to
$$
\delta(\cos^2\theta - 1) = \frac{\delta(\theta)}{|2\sin(0)|} + \frac{\delta(\theta - \pi)}{|2\sin\pi|},
$$
but as you can see, this function
blows up at the poles. So this means we cannot really
write
$$
\frac{\delta(\theta - \theta_0)}{\sin\theta} = \delta(\cos\theta - \cos\theta_0),
$$
correct? Is this one of those common physics habits of fudging up the math? I see the $\delta(\cos\theta)$ so much, I just feel that I am grossly misunderstanding something, but it is not easy to Google. Any insight is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Which physics textbooks? Which pages?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I remember seeing it in undergraduate E&M, but I cannot readily find it. I know it is in Barton's "Elements of Green’s Functions and Propagation". Also, Eq. (19) in this [this paper](https://www.scielo.br/j/rbef/a/xkcBhffNHP3yb6jzHjrcC7h/?format=pdf&lang=en) and Eq. (13) in this [web book](https://www.oceanopticsbook.info/view/light-and-radiometry/geometry)

Comment: In your original setting you need to avoid $\theta_0$ being a multiple of $\pi$ I guess. Which makes sense anyway because this causes a division by 0 either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***definition*** of the composition of the Dirac Delta, $\delta \circ f$, with a function $f$ assumes that $(1)$ $f$ is continuously differentiable and $(2)$ $f'$ is nowhere zero.  Under such assumptions then if $f(x_i)=0$ for $i=1, \cdots N$ we define $\delta\circ f$ by

$$\delta \circ f=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\delta_{x_i}}{|f'(x_i)|}$$

where $\langle \delta_{x_i}, \phi \rangle =\phi(x_i)$ for any $\phi\in C_C^\infty$.

Then, we have

$$\langle \delta\circ f, \phi\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\phi(x_i)}{|
f'(x_i)|}$$

Now, suppose $f(x)=\cos^2(x)-1$.  Note that $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$.  Note also $f'(x)=\sin(2x)$ so that $f'(0)=f'(\pi)=0$.   Hence, $f(x)=\cos^2(x)-1$ fails to satisfy the assumptions of the definition.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Would you be able to explain to me why so many substitute $\delta(\theta - \theta_0) / \sin\theta$ with $\delta(\cos\theta - \cos\theta_0)$? If you look at my comments above, I cite a couple references where this is used.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Let $f(\theta)=\cos(\theta)-\cos(\theta_0)$.  Then, $f(\theta_0)=0$ and $f'(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$.  Now use the definition for the composite Dirac Delta.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are nearing the end of my confusion. One last question, why do you use $f^\prime(\theta)$ instead of $f^\prime(\theta_0)$ if $\theta_0$ is the zero of $f(\theta)$ and the composite Dirac delta is defined only at the zeros?

Comment: I think this is the main source of my confusion. Basically, $\delta(\cos\theta - \cos\theta_0) = \delta(\theta - \theta_0)/|-\sin\theta_0|$ based on the definition of composite Dirac delta, no? So where did the non-constant $\sin\theta$ go? In my mind, $\delta(\theta - \theta_0)/\sin\theta = \delta(\cos\theta - \cos\theta_0)\sin\theta_0/\sin\theta$ based on the definitions provided.

Comment: Note that $f(x)\delta(x-x_0)=f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0)$

Comment: ahhh, I forgot about that property! You've cleared this up for a random physicist! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.